# Apache2 - mod_rewrite and .htacess - Not working 404 rule when i add other rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s 
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php 

ErrorDocument 404 /page-404.html
```

Like this when i open adress ending with .php it is auto redirected to the same adress but with ending of .html like i want.

When i remove these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /page-404.html
```

And i try to open non-existing directory i got my 404 error redirected to the page i want. The problem comes when i add the additional lines shown in my first code posted.

Where is the problem and why the 404 error redirection is not working in my first example ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-404.html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]

# make sure .php file exists for the requested .html file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```